# ggplot error: Making line graphs of three variables, then making a facet plot of those

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a facet plot of three line plots, and in each line plot there are three lines. I'd like to make the line corresponding to "oirf" to be a solid line, and both lines corresponding to "upperCI" and "lowerCI" to be dashed, either the same kind of dashed line or something very similar looking, like so:

[image: hand-drawn line plots]

But I'm getting an error I can't resolve.

Here's my data:

```
"countrySpellId","iso","country","step","indicator","vals"
38,"BLR","Belarus",0,"oirf",-0.19979745478058
38,"BLR","Belarus",1,"oirf",-0.182586795026907
38,"BLR","Belarus",2,"oirf",-0.242312010909111
106,"GEO","Georgia",0,"oirf",-0.154580915298088
106,"GEO","Georgia",1,"oirf",-0.0572862343086547
106,"GEO","Georgia",2,"oirf",-0.345457860190889
167,"KGZ","Kyrgyzstan",0,"oirf",0.960777168532119
167,"KGZ","Kyrgyzstan",1,"oirf",0.458003383067036
167,"KGZ","Kyrgyzstan",2,"oirf",0.190725669245905
38,"BLR","Belarus",0,"lowerCI",-0.357909781851253
38,"BLR","Belarus",1,"lowerCI",-0.411483619567094
38,"BLR","Belarus",2,"lowerCI",-0.514508124910321
106,"GEO","Georgia",0,"lowerCI",-0.323219475085121
106,"GEO","Georgia",1,"lowerCI",-0.236286319570866
106,"GEO","Georgia",2,"lowerCI",-0.540228716700013
167,"KGZ","Kyrgyzstan",0,"lowerCI",0.448913075973564
167,"KGZ","Kyrgyzstan",1,"lowerCI",0.0581860926615476
167,"KGZ","Kyrgyzstan",2,"lowerCI",-0.235580302805703
38,"BLR","Belarus",0,"upperCI",-0.0416851277099078
38,"BLR","Belarus",1,"upperCI",0.0463100295132811
38,"BLR","Belarus",2,"upperCI",0.0298841030920997
106,"GEO","Georgia",0,"upperCI",0.0140576444889454
106,"GEO","Georgia",1,"upperCI",0.121713850953557
106,"GEO","Georgia",2,"upperCI",-0.150687003681766
167,"KGZ","Kyrgyzstan",0,"upperCI",1.47264126109067
167,"KGZ","Kyrgyzstan",1,"upperCI",0.857820673472524
167,"KGZ","Kyrgyzstan",2,"upperCI",0.617031641297513
```

Here's how I'm trying to do the plots:

```
ggplot(data = oirfsFacetPlot2, aes(x = step, y = vals, group = countrySpellId,
                                   stat = "identity"))  +
                      geom_line(aes(linetype = indicator)) +
                      xlab("Month") + ylab("Percent change") +
                      theme_bw() + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,3,1)) +
                      scale_linetype_discrete(name  ="indicator",
                      breaks=c("lowerCI", "oirf","upperCI"))  +
                    facet_wrap( ~ country, scales = "free_y", nrow = 3 )
```

But then I get this error, which is somehow related to the `aes(linetype = indicator)` I think.

> Error: geom_path: If you are using dotted or dashed lines, colour, size and linetype must be constant over the line

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Image isn't showing up

Comment: delete the `group` from your `aes` (and the `stat` while you are at it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Richard pointed out, deleting the `group=countrySpellId` will eliminate the error, because you are trying to apply a group twice on two different variables (the `linetype` argument essentially does the same thing as `group`, it just means that that the different lines will also have different linetypes). The grouping on country will happen later in the `facet_wrap`.

Just doing that will get you three different linetypes that ggplot automatically chooses for you, but since you're particular about how those lines should look, you'll want to use `scale_linetype_manual`, which allows you to specify what linetype ggplot assigns to each factor level. You were on the right tract with scale_linetype_discrete!

Deleting the bad `group` argument and replacing the `scale_lientype_discrete` we have:

```
ggplot(data = oirfsFacetPlot2, aes(x = step, y = vals, stat = "identity"))  +
    geom_line(aes(linetype = indicator)) +
    xlab("Month") + ylab("Percent change") +
    theme_bw() + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,3,1)) +
    scale_linetype_manual(name = "indicator", values = c(2,1,2))  +
    facet_wrap( ~ country, scales = "free_y", nrow = 3 )
```

Comment: Very clear, much appreciated. I also noticed that I can make this particular plot without all the gathering by following the recipe from the R Graphics Cookbook [link](https://rpubs.com/escott8908/RGC_Ch4_Line_Graphs)